# Cannot send email using mail function

Tags: php

First question and first time looking at PHP so please bear with me.

I currently have the below jQuery which is calling a php file:

```
$(document).on('click', '#btnContactUs', function () {

    var name = $("input#name").val();
    var email = $("input#email").val();
    var subject = $("input#subject").val();
    var message = $("input#message").val();

    var dataString = 'name='+ name + '&email=' + email + '&subject=' + subject + '&message=' + message;


    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "php/message.php",
        data: dataString,
        success: function(response) { alert(response); }
      });

    return false;
    });
```

The console is logging the call as successful (XHR finished loading: POST "php/message.php").

Below is the full script in the file:

```
<?php
$to      = 'nobody@example.com';
$subject = 'the subject';
$message = 'hello';
$headers = 'From: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
?>
```

The email is not being sent/received (I am checking Spam also).

The files are hosted on a web server which has PHP installed. The alert box is popping up, but empty. The initial AJAX call is made from a submit button on a webpage.

EDIT: I am sending this to my personal email, which I have not included above.

EDIT: Even when visiting the URL of the script the email is still not being sent.

FINAL EDIT: The resolution is that my server did not have PHP mail installed - it is not supported as it is considered unreliable and therefore they recommend SMTP. To figure this out I used DrewT's solution of using SSH to check for "which sendmail"

Hope this scenario helps someone in the future.

Thanks all.

Comment: Give you a hand with what? What's the issue/question?

Comment: But the alert doesn't pop, does it?

Comment: Yes the alert does pop up.

Comment: @j08691 With sending an email from my form on a website.

Comment: So what's the issue? Also what do you mean by *the console is logging the call as successful*? You never call `console.log` so what is being logged and where?

Comment: How do you know nothing gets sent? Remember, the golden rule of asking questions - state what you tried, what you expected to see, and what you saw instead. Also might be a good idea to edit this into your question rather than commenting further.

Comment: The alert box popping up empty is exactly correct. If this is your script, then you are not returning anything from the web server so your request body is empty and therefore the alertbox pops up empty. I'm confused what you mean by the email is not being sent/received? How do you know  `nobody@example.com` is not receiving your email? Are you actually sending it to an email you control or are you checking outgoing smtp mail using some sort of utility?

Comment: Post your full code including the instance of setting your var dataString and I will help

Comment: I very much doubt this has anything to do with jquery or ajax. Does the `mail` function return true? Have you tried to do the same thing without using ajax at all? Create a temporary php file that sends a simple email to you when you visit the page. That way you can confirm that you know how to send emails correctly and that your server is in fact configured for it.

Comment: What makes me immediately suspicious is in your php file you're creating all these fields but not receiving anything from your var dataString. What did you expect dataString to do? Remember that the entire contents of your post request are being sent in your line `data: dataString,`

Comment: So a lot of comments on your updated code. In no particular order - it is unusual to manually serialize a data string, just pass a json object into there and let it get serialized automatically. Unrelated but you also [probably shouldn't return false](http://fuelyourcoding.com/jquery-events-stop-misusing-return-false/) and of course, as @DrewT pointed out, you are not doing anything with the data on the server. Again, this makes me suspect that you are not using `mail` correctly or your server is misconfigured. Do the test I recommended above.

Comment: Yes dataString is not being used yet, @GeorgeMauer I am trying to do just that, simply test if I can send an email. Should visiting the URL of the script in the browser cause the script to execute?

Comment: Does the script send any emails, when called directly without Ajax? I see, you are not using any POST variables. Maybe, your server is put into the spam blacklist, and the emails are ignored.

Comment: If you are not explicitly accepting only POST variables (which it looks like you're not), then yes, simply visiting the url should force an email to send. You should echo back whether mail returned true or false too. If you can hit the url via your browser directly and are getting the same results then you should remove the ajax/jquery tags and edit your question to simply "cannot send email using `mail` function"

Answer (score 0):

What seems to be happening is you are not sending your information in the correct format because you don't parse your var dataString on the server. I would try something like:

```
var name = $("input#name").val();
var email = $("input#email").val();
var subject = $("input#subject").val();
var message = $("input#message").val();
```

Then in your post function:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "php/message.php",
    data : { name: name, email: email, subject: subject, message: message },
    success: function (response, status, err) {
         // do stuff... 
         // NOTE: don't return false or it won't send
         // 'return false' only if the form is incomplete
         // and you don't want the email sent out prematurely
    }
});
```

Then to receive these vars in your PHP:

```
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$subject = $_POST['subject'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
```

Now you can send an email like this:

```
// Enter your send email address
$to = 'email@example.com';
// Add your headers
$header = "from: $name <$email>";

// only send it if we have all the data we need
if( $subject !== "" || " " && $message !== "" || " " && $name !== "" || " " && $mail_from !== "" || " " ) {

    $send_contact = mail($to,$subject,$message,$header);

    // check if message was sent
    // and provide some formatting (html) to send along in our response
    if ($send_contact) {
        echo '<div class="msg-sent">
                    Your message was sent successfully yay!
              </div>';
    }
    else {
        echo '<div class="msg-send-failed">
                  SEND FAILED :0
              </div>';
    }
}
else {
    echo '<div class="msg-had-empty">
                  YOU HAD EMPTY POST VARIABLES :0
          </div>';
}
```

Beyond that you will need to debug using the networks tab in your browser's inspector./ good luck!

Comment: Thanks @DrewT for the awesome answer, but my email will not send even when hitting the URL of the file manually. I will give this a try in the meantime.

Comment: If that is that case you will need to make sure that the PHP `mail()` function is enabled on your server. You can do this a number of ways, but first thing I would do is check your servers php and apache error logs and get the error code for what happens when it tries to use `mail()`

Comment: My code came directly from one of my servers so I know for sure it's working

Comment: Also, you will need to verify that the `sendmail` module is installed. You can do this over `SSH` to your server using `which sendmail` and if it's installed the server will return something like: `/usr/bin/sendmail`

Comment: Thanks Drew, will look at both these methods but downloading the error logs is taking some time...

Comment: Right so I do not have sendmail installed it seems - the response on SSH is "no sendmail in (null)" - I have contacted tech support for the server.

Comment: Hey @DennisY - depending on how your server and your permissions are configured on debian you can install using: `sudo apt-get install sendmail` and on ubuntu you can install using: `sudo yum install sendmail` folllowed by `sudo yum install m4`